# shunt current measurement with less voltage

Tags: current-measurement, shunt

Are there shunts available in market which can measure current of more than 200A but with voltage less than 50mV?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking recommendations for specific products are off-topic in this forum.  Check Help->Tour->Don't ask about.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are ! 200A at 50mV (max) means a 0.25mOhm(max) shunt. A quick google for "0.1mOhm shunt" gives [this datasheet](http://www.isotekcorp.com/sites/default/files/sites/default/files/pdfs/BAS.pdf) (among others) that is 0.1mOhm, 350A/15W rated.

Of course I suppose you know that magnetic-based current measurements are also available, being hall-effect based (DC or AC, Allegro seels them for up to 200A as IC, and more than 1000A with a bit more involved design) or induction based (for AC only). Both types offer additionnally galvanic isolation.

In the end, unless you have strong magnetic interference, high current means lower acceptable shunt voltage (for given power dissipation) and higher magnetic signal : both favor magnetic field based over shunt based...

Answer (score 2):

Shunts are typically made with standard full scale voltages, but there is nothing stopping you from buying an overrated shunt and using it at less current. Probably cheaper than a custom shunt.

For example, 500A 50mV shunts are readily available and inexpensive (at least the modest accuracy offshore type is). Such a shunt will have a drop of 50mV at 500A and thus 20mV at 200A.